# How to capture video of an iPhone simulator, while showing touches or cursor?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, quicktime, xcrun

What's the best way to capture video from an iPhone **simulator**, while capturing touch events and/or cursor? I've tried the Xcode tool `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo` but that doesn't capture any touch events. I've also tried QuickTime screen recording, which works for capturing touch, but doesn't snap to the simulator window, which doesn't look great, especially on the iPhones with notched screens.

Is there a good way to do this?